# Null reference exception on Interactivity Trigger

Tags: wpf, winforms, exception, triggers

With the following code in Xaml I get a null reference exception

```
    <toolkit:DataGrid x:Name="Roosters" Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Premies}" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" MaxWidth="2560" MaxHeight="1600">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding PremieRoostersSelectionChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=Roosters}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </toolkit:DataGrid>
```

Stacktrace:

```
at System.Windows.Markup.ReflectionHelper.IsPublicType(Type type)
at System.Windows.Markup.XamlTypeMapper.UpdateAttachedPropertyMethdodInfo(BamlAttributeInfoRecord attributeInfo, Boolean isSetter)
at System.Windows.Markup.XamlTypeMapper.UpdateAttachedPropertyGetter(BamlAttributeInfoRecord attributeInfo)
at System.Windows.Markup.PropertyDefinition.get_AttachedPropertyGetter()
at System.Windows.Markup.BamlCollectionHolder.InitDefaultValue()
at System.Windows.Markup.BamlCollectionHolder..ctor(BamlRecordReader reader, Object parent, Int16 attributeId, Boolean needDefault)
at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadPropertyIListStartRecord(BamlPropertyIListStartRecord bamlPropertyIListStartRecord)
at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadRecord(BamlRecord bamlRecord)
at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.Read(Boolean singleRecord)
at System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilderBamlTranslator.ParseFragment()
at System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilder.Parse()
at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
at PremiesWpf.Views.PremieRoosters.InitializeComponent()
```

I'm sure the problem is there since when I remove the Triggers part everything works. If I only remove the EventToCommand part the error still occurs.

This project is build in framework 3.5 (It's legacy and can't be upgraded as the impact is enormous).

This is also a WPF form that is being hosted in winforms to make things even worse.

The event in question:

```
    public DelegateCommand<Premie> PremieRoostersSelectionChanged { get; set; }

        PremieRoostersSelectionChanged = new DelegateCommand<Premie>(premie =>
        {
            Current = premie;
        });
```

Comment: Does this event have some code in it ? May we see it ?

Comment: Added the event, but mark that even without:  <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding PremieRoostersSelectionChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=Roosters}" /> it throws that exception.

Comment: Make sure `SelectedItem` is not null by ensuring you select one item in the `DataGrid`.

Comment: My breakpoint does not get hit when placed on the line Current=premie so current being null is not the problem.